# upload files to aws s3 from node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am using aws sdk to uplod user input image and then get the image link from aws and i will store the link in mongoDB. In that case when i run .upload() it is async.

```
const imgSRC = [];


for (let img of image) {
console.log(img);
const params = {
  Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
  Key: `${img.originalname}_${userID}`,
  Body: img.buffer,
};
s3.upload(params,  (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ msg: "server error" });
  }
   imgSRC.push(data.Location);
  console.log(imgSRC);
});
```

}

```
const newPost = new Post({
userID: userID,
contentID: contentID,
posts: [
  {
    caption: caption,
    data: imgSRC,
  },
],
```

});
const post = await newPost.save();

in that case when the .save to mongodb run, there is no imgLinks from aws yet. How can i fix that things.

I've already tried async and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Promise.all()` in this manner

```
const uploadImage = (obj) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
      Key: obj.key,
      Body: obj.body,
    }
    s3.upload(params, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return reject(error);
      }
      return data;
    });
  })
}

const mainFunction = async () => {
  const promises = [];
  for (let img of image) {
    const options = {
      key: `${img.originalname}_${userID}`,
      body: img.buffer
    };
    promises.push(uploadImage(options));
  }
  const result = await Promise.all(promises);
  const imgSRC = result.map((r) => { return r.Location });
  return imgSRC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `await` on `s3.upload` method you should remove the callback for this method.

```
try {
  const data = await s3.upload(params);
  imgSRC.push(data.Location);
  console.log(imgSRC);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(500).json({ msg: "server error" });
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: it is not working for some reason. when i log out that data in console. it said data is undefied.Or i think there is a typo or missing some words in my code